# Redirect Application to external Url before application loads: Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6, microservices, angular-routing

So the case is, On the app component I check if user is authenticated and if not, redirect the user to a rest api call which has the login page.
The current code has the api redirection call  on constructure of app.component.ts
So what happens is, 
The html pages of app.component loads for 1 second and then redirection takes place.
How can I redirect user to the rest api url before any html (DOM elements ) loaded on screen

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user is logged in in your route with [canActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

For example:

app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: HomelayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [LoginGuardService]
}]
```

Your login-guard.service.ts

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
 // Implement here your auth check logic
  if (localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')) {
    return true;
  }

  // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url and return false
  this.router.navigate(['login'], {
    queryParams: {
      returnUrl: state.url
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```